# using a Logitech camera in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, logitech

I have been trying to use my logitech camera using:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
```

My laptop already have a built-in camera and it's working fine
I'm using openCV 2.3 in Visual Studio 2010
All sources i'm finding are using libraries for VS 2008
I don't think that they work for 2010 (I've tried one before)
Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: It looks like C. C++ would be something like `cv::VideoCapture cap(1);`

Comment: Ummm, I don't know if this works. But can you provide me with a simple example to test it? I'm relatively a beginner at openCV

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV Capture from external camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248201/opencv-capture-from-external-camera)

Comment: I doubt it will help, but I put something [here](http://pastebin.com/i0Kb2xNv). But I use linux and I can figure out what is going on at the OS level, although for my logitech camera I didn't have to do anything special.

Comment: @karlphillip it is a possible duplication, I've seen that one before posting (stackoverflow has a very nice search engine when you type the title) however, that question had several different circumstances as well as it didn't help me much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the reference of your logitech camera ?
Here is a [list](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FullOpenCVWiki) of compatible camera tested with opencv.

Comment: could it be the camera itself? I thought that the method i'm using cannot be used for cameras connected via USB

Comment: VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int device) -- device = id of the opened video capturing device (i.e. a camera index). If there is a single camera connected, just pass 0.